# Why the file is not written when I did fwrite() to it?

Tags: c

I'm basically trying to create a simple program that simulates a screen whose value is generated randomly and are outputted to a bmp file. However, there are some trouble in the file operation.. when the fwrite is called, the file stays at zero bytes, meaning nothing was written to that file.. I've tried changing the fopen modes (e.g "w+b", "wb+", "wb") but still no luck.. here is the code anyway

```
char resultFileName[BUFSIZ];
char currentDirectory[BUFSIZ];
//char generatedFileFolder[] = "\\generatedFile";
FILE *resultFile;

getcwd(currentDirectory, sizeof(currentDirectory));
snprintf(resultFileName, sizeof(resultFileName), "%s%s", currentDirectory, "\\result.bmp");
resultFile = fopen(resultFileName, "w+b");

BITMAPFILEHEADER bmfh;

BITMAPINFOHEADER bmih;

fwrite(&bmfh, sizeof(bmfh), 1, resultFile);
fwrite(&bmih, sizeof(bmih), 1, resultFile);
```

what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: did you call `fclose(resuleFile)` ? it is required at some point...

Comment: [fflush](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fflush/) would also work

Comment: Also note that there may be operating system specific buffering on lower levels as well as the stdio buffering going on with `FILE`. On POSIX systems (like e.g. Linux or macOS) you typically use [`fsync`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fsync.html) for that.

Comment: Read [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call [`fclose`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fclose).

The I/O functions starting with `f` is buffered, which means they only write periodically (when reaching the maximum buffer size), or when you close it.

Since C is not a garbage-collected language (or language with the concept of destructor), your buffers are not flushed unless you flush it or close the file.

Comment: Files are implicitly closed on program termination.

Comment: @Olaf only the file descriptors are cleaned up by OS, which is non-buffered (or, the buffer is transparent). This is C, not Python nor C++.

Comment: I very well know this is not C++ or Python. Hmm, maybe that is an implementation matter, long time I worked with files in C on a normal desktop. Nevertheless, the code shown is only a snippet; we don't know if OP closes the files.

Comment: my bad, I've forgotten to close the file thinking that it is printf.. thanks anyway!

Comment: @TatsuyukiIshi, The C standard says:  *If the main function returns to its original caller, or if the exit function is called, all open files are closed (hence all output streams are flushed) before program termination.*

Comment: @Olaf: that's why I just commented and not answered: the question was unclear about when the files were seen empty. With the debugger, of course, they can be empty at this point, but on exit, no way.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Yes, but some people prefer shotgun answers over snipers.